# Having a sound clip play and be looped as long as the button is pressed down and stops as soon as it is released

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python

I am able to have the script running when I have the code set to

> pygame.mixer.music.play

but if I do

> pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)

I get an error stating

> CallbackSetToNone: The callback was set to None. This may have been unintentional e.g. btn.when_pressed = pressed() instead of btn.when_pressed = pressed

```
from gpiozero import Button
import pygame
pygame.init()

siren = pygame.mixer.music.load('sound.mp3')
start = pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
button = Button(17)
while True:
        button.when_pressed = start
        button.when_released = pygame.mixer.music.stop
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I am using the pygame.mixer.Sound object which is more suited to playing sounds rather than music. pygame also seems to recommend using WAVs rather than mp3 files. I've had to use GPIO4 (built in pull up resistor) for my Button as I'm on a Pi4.

```
from gpiozero import Button
import pygame,time

def sirenStart():
    print('start')
    siren.play(loops=-1)

def sirenStop():
    print('stop')
    siren.stop()

pygame.init()
siren = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound.wav')

button = Button(4)
button.when_pressed = sirenStart
button.when_released = sirenStop

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response I tried that but was getting an error saying `button.when_pressed = sirenStart
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 148, in __setattr__
    return super(GPIOBase, self).__setattr__(name, value)
AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: What version of python and gpiozero are you using?

Comment: @DDevelops May you please answer the question of *@CoderMike*?